# jQuery prependTo() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like this:

```html
<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the `ca_title` div and move it into the `photo_room_f` div for every `usa_img_bg`.

I use this code:

```js
$.each($('.usa_img_bg'), function(index, element) { 
    $(element).children(".ca_title").prependTo(".photo_room_f");
});
```

but it gets me all titles and puts them all on every `usa_img_bg` div.
How can I make it get only the `ca_title` that's in every single `usa_img_bg`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are appending to all the `.photo_room_f` elements, you need to `find()` the one related to the `.usa_img_bg` of the iteration. Try this:

```js
$('.usa_img_bg').each(function(i, e) { 
    var $room = $(this).find(".photo_room_f");
    $(this).find(".ca_title").appendTo($room);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector you're using inside `prependTo` is a standard jquery selector and it doesn't know you're only interested in the current `element`, so it will be returning ALL elements on the page with a class of `photo_room_f`.

Try something like this:

```
$.each($('.usa_img_bg'), function(index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);

    $el.children(".ca_title").prependTo($el.find(".photo_room_f"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each($('.usa_img_bg'), function() { 
    $(this).children(".ca_title").prependTo($(this).find('.photo_room_f'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `context` parameter of [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

`.prependTo($(".photo_room_f", element));`

where `element` is `context`: `.usa_img_bg`

```js
$.each($(".usa_img_bg"), function(index, element) {
  $(element).children(".ca_title").prependTo($(".photo_room_f", element));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="usa_img_bg">
  <div class="ca_title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="img_box">
    <div class="photo_room_f">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor si amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```